# python + mongo issue

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm playing around with mongodb (documentation isn't very complete):

```
tmpQuery = collection.find({"title_full": "kdsljfklsadfklj"})
print tmpQuery[0]['title_full']
```

That just echo's "no such item for Cursor instance", what is an if statement to determine if the variable tmpQuery has a valid result set and not empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh geez, issue solved with:

```
tmpQuery.count()
```